# Как анимировать activity при создании

Tags: android, android-animation

Хочу сделать анимацию  при старте активити. В [этой](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/animation/overridependingtransition.php) статья все детально описано, там есть несколько вариантов. Вариант со стилями пока не рассматривал, хотел понять, как можно анимировать вход в активити через Java-код, если таким способом сделать не получается                 `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in_left, R.anim.out_right);` , так как в конкретном случае переход из активити в активити происходит через `Notification`, а вставить анимацию просто в `onCreate` нужной мне активити вот таким образом:

```
Animation animRotateIn_icon = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.rotate);

icon.startAnimation(animRotateIn_icon);
```

не получается, не могу понять как применить анимацию не к какому то одному элементу, а всему layout'у

Comment: попробуйте применить анимацию к леяуту, в котором все лежит - присвойте ему id в xml, и найдите его через findViewById(), а дальше работайте с ним, как с обычным View

Comment: @metalurgus получилось!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="5dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<TextView
    android:background="#b123d9"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Number"
    android:id="@+id/tvTxt"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

### MainActivity.class

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    main_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    main_layout.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_in));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

При запуске activity, пример :

```
this.startActivity(new Intent(activity, Import.class));
this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_in, R.anim.activity_out);
```

R.anim.activity_in :

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="200" />
</set>
```

R.anim.activity_out :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:duration="200" />
</set>
```

Comment: Ваш способ требует перехода с одной активити или это можно сделать даже если активити всего одна в проекте ?

Comment: Даже если activity одна